# How would I do an Angular JS ng-repeat on this JSON parse?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, content-management-system, hybrid-mobile-app

How would I do an Angular JS ng-repeat on this JSON parse?

```
    .controller('TeamsCtrl', function($scope) {  

    var text = '{"employees":[' +
        '{"name":"John Doe"},' +
        '{"name":"Sam Doe"},' +
        '{"name":"Jack Doe"}]}';  
    /* create scope property that will be recognized in view*/
    $scope.tasks =  JSON.parse(text);

});
```

Here is the area I want populated with the new content:

```
    <ion-content class="has-header" ng-controller="TeamsCtrl">
  <div class="list card" ng-repeat="employee in tasks.employee" ng-click="showActionsheet()">
    <div class="item item-divider">
       <div>{{employee.name}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: same way you do `ng-repeat` for any array. There is no angular code shown here,  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning the parsed results to a scope variable

Controller should be more like:

```
.controller('TeamsCtrl', function($scope) {  

    var text = '{"employees":[' +
        '{"name":"John Doe"},' +
        '{"name":"Sam Doe"},' +
        '{"name":"Jack Doe"}]}';  
    /* create scope property that will be recognized in view*/
    $scope.tasks =  JSON.parse(text);

});
```

Then in markup you can do something like:

```html
<div ng-repeat="employee in tasks.employees">
    <div>{{employee.name}}</div>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3uhBWepghqlpPrzj9634)**</kbd>

Comment: I've tried that and it just comes '{{id}}:{{employee.name}}' instead of populating all the names

Comment: did you initialize `ng-app`? Any errors in console?

Comment: see demo link i added to answer

Comment: Still doesn't appear... I've updated my question with the new code in. Can you please have a look?

Comment: works fine in demo I created. Not sure what else I can do to help without a demo that replicates your problem and seeing more of your angular code. Are any errors thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the Json object all you need is to set it in the scope and iterate over it 
.

```
<h3>Output:</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(id,emp) in items">{{id}}: {{emp.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Js Fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/921mux0u/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having correct list of employees than you can use like

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employees>
    <div>{{id}}:{{employee.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in obj.employees">{{item.name}}</div>
```

[Check my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7pimBA?p=preview)